# How to use frollapply to a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have to use frollapply for a function having sliding window size 26. if panel is a data.table how can I use it for following function

```
testFn <- function(panel){
panel <- panel[, .(variable.weeks = max(QUANTITY_2)), 
                          by = c("ITEM", "Date", "QUANTITY", "MIN_PRICE", "saleflag")]

 return(panel)

}
```

when I am using

```
library(data.table)
setDT(panel.merged)
panel<- frollapply(panel.merged,26, testFn)
```

which gives error

```
Error in .(variable.weeks = max(QUANTITY_2)) : 
could not find function "."
```

Comment: Possilvly either ``panel`` isn't a data.table or you didn't load ``library(data.table)``

Comment: Yes.. I have loaded..

Comment: did you try `setDT(panel.merged)` before passing it `testFn()`?

Comment: @zainulabid are you sure it's a data.table object?

Comment: Did you read function documentation and examples? I spent some time writing those...

Comment: Save yourself (and others) time in future by consulting documentation before you go to SO.

Comment: @jangorecki I was still confusing while applying this to my dataset..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frollapply` passes a vector to its function, not the whole frame. You can see this by debugging the function (`debug(testFn)`), calling `frollapply(panel.merged,26, testFn)`, and confirming that `panel` inside the function is just a vector.

My guess is that you need something like

```r
panel.merged[, variable.weeks := frollapply(QUANTITY_2, 26, max),
             by = c("ITEM", "Date", "QUANTITY", "MIN_PRICE", "saleflag")]
```